# From factor to Numeric in R

Tags: r

I am having big trouble trying to convert a set of 53 factor variables to numeric. Here are a couple of the functions I tried but none of them are working :

```
sapply(dataset, function(x) transform(as.character(x)))
```

and then

```
sapply(dataset, function(x) transform(as.numeric(x)))
```

I also tried it with lapply, but same thing...

```
as.numeric(levels(factor))
```

doesnt work either and finally I tried to do it one by one:

```
transform(dataset, s1 = as.numeric(s1), s2= as.numeric(s2)...etc)
```

Could somebody please help me ? I also have a couple of missing values NA and M within the variables so I dont know how I can adjust for that. 
Thanks !

Comment: Can you show us some basic example data? It will make it much easier to fix. Provide a minimal working example (MWE) so we can debug the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In addition to @TARehman, info on how to give a [reproducible example can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is one of the most common questions on SO (and elsewhere), answered in the R-FAQ 7.10 .  see http://cran.r-project.org/ and click on the FAQ link.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't provide a reproducible example, this might work:

```
df[,c(2:54)] <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[,c(2:54)])))
```

where `c(2:54)` stands for the columns you want to change to numeric